# Com relação ao React

Tags: html, funções, react

Estou com uma dúvida, com relação ao `react`, eu queria mudar o conteúdo da página ao clicar, porém o site reconhece só como object.

**Função**

```
import React from 'react';   

//funções 
export  function botao2(){
    document.querySelector('.CassandraText').innerHTML = 'Downloading Cassandra';
    document.querySelector('.resumo').innerHTML = <h3>Latest Beta Version</h3>;
    console.log('clicado');
}
```

**O botão que chama a função**

```
<button onClick={botao2}> 
    Download Cassandra
</button>
```

No caso eu estava tentando abrir o `<h3>`, mas quando mando pro `component`, ele aparece como `object`.

Comment: Não tente usar o React, se é novo, aprenda JavaScript, HTML e CSS, depois pode tentar ir pro React ou outra biblioteca/framework

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que dar um estudado como funciona [react](/questions/tagged/react), a maneira de alterar telas, variáveis, etc. Realmente antes de entrar no mundo [react](/questions/tagged/react) dê uma estudada em [html](/questions/tagged/html), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) e [css](/questions/tagged/css) pelo menos o básico para não ficar perdido com isso.

Ao criar um componente no `React` para alterar contéudo segue um exemplo minimo:

```js
function App() {
  const [nome, setNome] = React.useState('Inicial');
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{nome}</h3>
      <button
          onClick={e => 
            setNome('Alterado com sucesso')}
       >Alterar</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

E assim começa a utilizar e a ideia central de como alterar conteúdos de páginas.

Comment: o duro é que eu quero alterar a tag de outro componente, que não é esse do botão.

Comment: Teria uma forma deu utilizar o query selector para adicionar essas tags?

Comment: Não é com querySelector que faz isso, React é uma forma especifica de criar componentes, eu te passei um exemplo, o grande problema foi que sua pergunta não tem um foco especifico e você quer misturar coisas ... ! React tem que ser feito no mundinho dele! com as funções e caracteristicas dele ... @use

Comment: `o duro é que eu quero alterar a tag de outro componente, que não é esse do botão` seja especifico, o exemplo é para criar uma realidade que você não sabia, mas, é assim que deve ser feito, agora não sei bem seu problema poderia explicar?